# How to create dropdown times listed change in php?

Tags: php, time, drop-down-menu

I want to have a dropdown times listed change.
Times begin 1.5 hours after curent time. So, if
the current time is 10:31 then the first available time 
is 12:30 pm-1:00pm

if the current time is 2:31pm
the first available time 
is 2:30 pm-3:00pm.

here is the dropdown

12:30pm - 1:00pm
1:00pm - 1:30pm
1:30pm - 2:00pm
2:00pm - 3:30pm
2:30pm - 3:00pm
3:00pm - 3:30pm
3:30pm - 4:00pm
4:00pm - 4:30pm
5:00pm - 5:30pm
5:30pm - 6:00pm

Any help?
Thanks!
Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use `time` and `date` functions, round to half hours.

```
$timeAtHalfHour = time() - ( time() % (60*30));
//$timeAtHalfHour += 90*60;  //IDK IF YOU WANT THIS?
$endTime = strtotime('6:00 pm');
$numIntervals = ($endTime - $timeAtHalfHour) / (60*30);
echo "<select name='timeInterval'>";
$strTime1 = date('h:iA', $timeAtHalfHour);
foreach(range(1,$numIntervals) as $cur)
{
   $thisTime = $timeAtHalfHour + 30*60*$cur;
   $strTime2 = date('h:iA', $thisTime);
   echo "<option value=$cur>$strTime1 - $strTime2 </option><br />";
   $strTime1 = $strTime2;
}
echo "</select>";
```

---

### EDIT

```
$timeAtHalfHour = time() - ( time() % (60*30));
//$timeAtHalfHour += 90*60;  //IDK IF YOU WANT THIS?
$endTime = strtotime('6:00 pm');
$numIntervals = ($endTime - $timeAtHalfHour) / (60*30);
$strTime1a = date('h:iA', $timeAtHalfHour); $strTime2a = date('h:iA', $timeAtHalfHour + 4*60*30);
$optionStr1 = ''; $optionStr2 = '';
foreach(range(1,$numIntervals) as $cur)
{
   $thisTime1 = $timeAtHalfHour + 30*60*$cur; $thisTime2 = $thisTime1 + (60*30*4);
   $strTime1b = date('h:iA', $thisTime1); $strTime2b = date('h:iA', $thisTime2);
   $optionStr1 .= "<option value=$cur>$strTime1a - $strTime1b </option><br />";
   $optionStr2 .= "<option value=$cur>$strTime2a - $strTime2b </option><br />";
   $strTime1a = $strTime1b; $strTime2a = $strTime2b;
}
echo "<select name='firstTime'>$optionStr1</select>";
echo "<select name='secondTime'>$optionStr2</select>";
```

Its just pretty much making a second time parallel to the first time, just 4 half hour intervals ahead.

Comment: should first option be the interval we in now, or now + 1.5 hours?  you state it both ways in your question

Comment: Thanks! great! but I need the start time 12:30pm - 1:00pm  and the end time 5:30pm - 6:00pm ? how to do this ? Thank you so much!

Comment: i thought the start time is either now or now + 1.5hr?  `$timeAtHalfHour = strtotime('12:30 pm')` if thats what you want

Comment: Hi Jon How to create two drop down menus that the second dropdown ahead of two hrs on the first menu selected? for example i have select 12:30pm-1:00pm in the first dropdown the second dropdown first available time is 2:30 pm-3:00pm. How to do this? do tyou haev exampel of this? thanks!

Comment: im not really sure where you'tr going with this, but what you describe isnt hard at al.  its just two `<select>` with corresponding set of `<option>`s instead of one.  note that for the values i just put integers kind of arbitrarily.  depending on what your next page (the one that takes the action of the form when it is submitteD) this may or may not be what you want.  check the edit i posted

Comment: Its great, what about chained select on that? do you know how? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:
 - For each timeperiod listed in the dropdown, calculate the unix timestamp (`strtotime()`) of the start time. Then you calculate the current timestamp (`time()`). Then remove all timeperiods where the timestamp of the start time is less then 90*60 seconds from the current time: `if($curTime+(90*60) > $startTimestampOfPeriod){}`

Comment: Which part? You can look up the function and how they work on php.net and use them in your application, I've given a pseudo example.